# Using variables to set attribute values in a tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use the *vis* variable in the display attribute as shown in the code. There are no errors in the console but the paragraph wont hide on pressing the button.

```
let vis = false;
const handleClick = () => {
    vis = !vis;
    render();
};

const render = () => {
    const jsx = (
        <div>
            <h1>Toggle</h1>
            <p display = {vis ? "block" : "none"} >Hi</p>
            <button onClick = {handleClick}>{vis ? 'Hide details' : 'Show details'}</button>
        </div>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("app"));
}

render();
```

Here's a simple and working alternative:

```
let vis = false;
const handleClick = () => {
    vis = !vis;
    render();
};

const render = () => {
    const jsx = (
        <div>
            <h1>Toggle</h1>
            {vis ? <p>Hi</p> : ''}
            <button onClick = {handleClick}>{vis ? 'Hide details' : 'Show details'}</button>
        </div>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("app"));
}

render();
```

The problem is I am not asking for other ways to do it. I just want to understand if I can use *vis* in *display* like I did in my first code snippet.

Comment: You might want to make `vis` into state. `const [vis, setVis] = useState(false);` and then to change vis you would do `setVis(x=> !x);`

Comment: @David784 I understand there are other better ways to deal with this. But I want to know if its possible to use that variable like I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the paragraph wont hide on pressing the button.

It's the `display` property on the paragraph. This is a CSS property, not a stand-alone element attribute. That means it should go inside the `style` attribute, like this:

```
<p style={{display: vis ? "block" : "none"}} >Hi</p>
```

After making that one change, your code worked for me. Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your are trying to achieve?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>Toggle</button>
      {toggle && <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>}
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```